# How to make rspec with multiple parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am a beginner in Rails and using old version 4.0 with Rspec. I want to test on the controller where my route is following.

```
/properties/:property_id/build
```

I can test /properties/1 by writing the following

```
get :show, id: properties
expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
```

But not sure how can I write property's id number to build controller whose route is above. It means to show the method I have to put properties id and build but later on for update I have to put two parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `property_id` with params like

```
get :build, params: { property_id: property.id } #You pass additional parameters with this.
```

Here property_id is `:property_id` in `/properties/:property_id/build`

Answer (score 1):

If its a `get` request then,

```
get :build, params: {id: properties, second_param: "something" }
```

(assuming `properties` is the `Property` object from your example and the second param is `second_param`)

Comment: There is one get request and one post request but params are in url too!

Comment: you can put all the params inside `params` key to test

Comment: but I am still getting error undefined local variable or method `properties' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PropertiesBuildController

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner so I think I got the incorrect understanding of Routing and controller tests. As it was still giving an error and after discussing with another programmer. I finally resolved using the following pattern.

```
get :new, property_id: property.id
```